# How to properly filter by enum value in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, enums, filtering

If I have an enum defined like this:

```
export enum State {
    Archived = 0,
    OnShoppingListChecked = 1,
    OnShoppingListUnchecked = 2
}
```

and a class that uses the enum:

```
import { State } from "./State";
export class GroceryDto {
  public name: string = null;
  public currentState: State = null;
}
export default GroceryDto;
```

I have some code that is trying to filter based on the `currentState` of `GroceryDto`, but is not qualifying anything to be entered into the array.

```
//...some code to fetch data
let activeGroceries = response.data.activeGroceries as GroceryDto[]; //casts correctly to an array of 4 items
let visibleGroceries = activeGroceries.filter(
  g => g.currentState === State.OnShoppingListUnchecked
);
//visibleGroceries is empty but should return the same 4 values
```

I was able to get the result I wanted by casting to a string, but that seems like it should be unnecessary if I'm using typescript.

```
let filtered = visibleGroceries.filter(
  g =>
    g.currentState.toString() === State[State.OnShoppingListUnchecked]
);
```

Comment: What does the data in `activeGroceries` look like ? maybe you are getting `strings` from the server instead on the enum values (which appear to be numeric)

Comment: If the values you're getting from network call are strings (and it seems they are) - you can use string enums: `enum State { Archived = 'Archived' ... }`

Comment: You were both correct, `public currentState: State = null;` in `GroceryDto` was getting serialized from the server as a string and not an enum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems the discrepancy was in how the server was sending back the data, `currentState` on each `GroceryDto` was being sent over as a string. Changing the enum definition like @Aleksey mentioned solved my problem:

```
export enum State {            
        Archived = "Archived",
        OnShoppingListChecked = "OnShoppingListChecked",
        OnShoppingListUnchecked = "OnShoppingListUnchecked"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Be advised, that `enum`a in TypeScript are quite... well they might be misunderstood, and always might be used as string-based and numeric-based type.

If you use your `enum` in form like you presented:

```
State.OnShoppingListUnchecked
```

Then it will be represented as number and compared against numeric value of 1. But consider following cross-matching enum code:

```
a === State['OnShoppingListUnchecked'] // compare against 1
a === State[State['OnShoppingListUnchecked']] // compare against 'OnShoppingListUnchecked' string
a === State[State[State['OnShoppingListUnchecked']]] // Again against numeric 1
// ... and so one
```

Probably you are getting from server side string, not a number, and thus your checks are failed. You can add a bit of automation to that checking in following way:

```
let toCompare = 1 // Field you wish to compare against
if(typeof(compareValue) === 'number') {
  return State[toCompare ] === compareValue // Compare number against number
} else if (typeof(compareValue) === 'string') {
  return State[State[toCompare ] === compareValue // compare input string against string representation of enum
}
```

To ensure, regardless of is input string or number, you will be always comparing against correct `enum` entry.

And keep in mind, string-based enums are supported since TyeScript 2.4 and upper, and in my personal opinion usage of them shall be minimized, mostly because number-based enums are convenient way to choose some additional information from array-arranged structures, while string-based are impossible to use this way:

```
enum NamesEnum {
    NAME0 = 0,
    NAME1 = 1
};

namesToDisplay: string[] = [
  'Name1 display value',
  'Name2 display value'
];

let enumVal = someFunctionThatGetsEnum(); // Works only for number-based enums
this.currentDisplay = this.namesToDisplay[enumVal];
```

and in template:

```
<p>{{ currentDisplay  }} </p>
```

If you don't have use-case scenario for array indexing, then string-based enums can be replaced with String Literal Types with same benefits as enums gives you but with less worrying about type and compatibility issues.